# How to Generate dynamic URL for eCommerce website filters in jquery or c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to Generate the dynamic UELs for my eCommerce site.

Suppose when i click the checkbox of price it will show like

http://localhost:123?price=35-100

and when we click on color then it will show

http://localhost:123?price=35-100&color=black

if the above scenario is not possible

i want to bind both in a single parameter  like

http://localhost:123?price=35-100/color=black

Comment: To get started please refer Url: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/219d4d/implement-search-paging-and-sort-in-mvc-5/

Comment: Definitely you can. You have to implement it